# Hibernate - Native SQL ошибка запроса Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с возникшей ошибкой: 
**org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Недопустимое имя столбца**

Сам запрос выглядит так :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

    String sql = "select nkl,psum,lsum,ltl,tzav, lth,dv,  dn,nv,nvp from"+
            "(select nkl,psum,lsum,ltl, tzav, lth,dv,  dn ,nv,nvp from"+
            "(select nkl, tzav, psum,lsum,ltl, lth, dv,  dn,nv,nvp from"+
            "(select nkl, tzav, psum,lsum,ltl, lth, ROUND(Diam,2) dv, ROUND(Ddiam,2) dn,nv,nvp from zxp.valpr"+
            " where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl,MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=0 group by nkl ) and pvn=0 and rop=0)))order by 1";
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    //query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    query.addEntity(workval.class);
    List res = query.list();       
    request.getRequestDispatcher("4kl/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

**workval.java:**

```
package four_mill;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public class workval implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer nkl;
private Integer ukey;
private Integer psum;
private Integer lsum;
private Integer ltl;
private Date    tzav;
private Date    tviv;
private Integer lth;
private Integer dv;
private Integer dn;
private Integer nv;
private Integer nvp;
private Integer pvn;
private Integer rop;


public workval(Integer nkl, Integer ukey, Integer psum, Integer lsum, Integer ltl, Integer lth,
        Integer dv, Integer dn, Integer nv, Integer nvp,Integer pvn,Integer rop, Date tzav, Date tviv) {
    this.nkl   = nkl;
    this.ukey = ukey;
    this.psum = psum;
    this.lsum = lsum;
    this.ltl  = ltl;
    this.lth  = lth;
    this.dv   = dv;
    this.dn   = dn;
    this.nv   = nv;
    this.nvp  = nvp;
    this.pvn  = pvn;
    this.rop  = rop;
    this.tzav = tzav;
    this.tviv = tviv;
}

public workval(){

}

public Integer getNkl() {
    return nkl;
}

public void setNkl(Integer nkl) {
    this.nkl = nkl;
}

public Integer getUkey() {
    return ukey;
}

public void setUkey(Integer ukey) {
    this.ukey = ukey;
}
public Integer getPsum() {
    return psum;
}
public void setPsum(Integer psum) {
    this.psum = psum;
}
public Integer getLsum() {
    return lsum;
}
public void setLsum(Integer lsum) {
    this.lsum = lsum;
}
public Integer getLtl() {
    return ltl;
}
public void setLtl(Integer ltl) {
    this.ltl = ltl;
}
public Date getTzav() {
    return tzav;
}
public void setTzav(Date tzav) {
    this.tzav = tzav;
}
public Date getTviv() {
    return tviv;
}
public void setTviv(Date tviv) {
    this.tviv = tviv;
}
public Integer getLth() {
    return lth;
}
public void setLth(Integer lth) {
    this.lth = lth;
}
public Integer getDv() {
    return dv;
}
public void setDv(Integer dv) {
    this.dv = dv;
}
public Integer getDn() {
    return dn;
}
public void setDn(Integer dn) {
    this.dn = dn;
}
public Integer getNv() {
    return nv;
}
public void setNv(Integer nv) {
    this.nv = nv;
}
public Integer getNvp() {
    return nvp;
}
public void setNvp(Integer nvp) {
    this.nvp = nvp;
}
public Integer getPvn() {
    return pvn;
}
public void setPvn(Integer pvn) {
    this.pvn = pvn;
}
public Integer getRop() {
    return rop;
}
public void setRop(Integer rop) {
    this.rop = rop;
}

}
```

**workv.hbm.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="four_mill.workval" table="valpr" catalog="ZXP">
        <id name="ukey" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UKEY" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="nkl" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="NKL"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="psum" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="PSUM"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="lsum" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="LSUM"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="ltl" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="LTL"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="lth" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="LTH"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="dv" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="DV"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="dn" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="DN"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="nv" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="NV"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="nvp" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="NVP"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="pvn" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="PVN"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
         <property name="rop" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ROP"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="tzav" type="date">
            <column name="TZAV"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="tviv" type="date">
            <column name="TVIV"  not-null="false" unique="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Тот же запрос в DBeaver:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема ? Всем большое спасибо за помощь, и совет.

Если сделать запрос на выборку всех данных в БД ошибка таже

```
String sql = "select * from zxp.valpr";
```

Добился вывода при Select * from zxp.valpr
Ошибкой было, да это даже ошибкой не назовеш :

```
ROUND(Diam,2) dv, ROUND(Ddiam,2) dn
```

В базе есть стобцы Diam и  Ddiam но нет dv и dn. Заменив имена и конфиг hbm Ошибка при выполнении моего основного запроса осталась прежней. Неужели Hibernate настолько вредный в использовании ? может отказаться от данного фреймворка ? Посоветуйте как быть, запросы с БД для моего проекта главная задача, а тут такие неприятные нюансы, незнаю как быть ?

Упрастил запрос, проблема не решена:

```
String sqll = "select nkl, tzav, psum,lsum,ltl, lth, diam, ddiam,nv,nvp from zxp.valpr where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl,MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=0 group by nkl ) and pvn=0 and rop=0 order by 1";
```

Comment: Ну если составляете запрос простой строкой, попробуйте напрямую в оракле его провести. Ругается или нет?

Comment: Хотел выложить скрин, что напрямую в оракле запрос работает, даже работает через jdbc драйвер напрямик:

Comment: Hibernate вам намекает, что все кто присвает подобные нечитабельные имена переменным должны страдать. :)

Comment: простите но БД формировал не я, а переменные в java это я уже переименовал от безысходности.

Comment: Ну раз запрос корректен, то ошибка в workv.hbm.xml. Видать вы опечатались в имени какого-то столбца. И кстати странно, вродь он должен указывать что за имя некорректно.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim Я уже перепроверил n-раз всё совпадает, может причина в чем-то еще ?

Comment: Вы логи хибернейта смотрели? Хибернейт может показывать SQL который он пытается выполнить. Его и надо проверять.

Comment: @Vartlok Дело в том что он выводит в логах правильный запрос а далее ошибка **org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Недопустимое имя столбца** Выше в теме отредактировал изминения, но проблема не решена

Comment: Может я чего-то не знаю. Но с комбинированными запросами у гиперсети проблемы. Вы ведь "замапили" исходную таблицу? А запрос в итоге возвращает таблицу с другой структурой. Верно?

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim Конечно замапил. Возвращал ROUND(Diam,2) dv, ROUND(Ddiam,2) dn, в этом запросе я оставляю 2 знака после запятой, и ответ поместить в dn и dv. Какого-то рода да, верно. Сейчас я ROUND выкинул оставил пока Diam и Ddiam И всеравно получаю ошибку Недопустимого столбца. Теперья точно уверен что имена запроса совпадают с именами  таблице, но ошибка прежняя

Comment: Ну кстати да, если вы решили руками писать запросы вам не особо нужен hibernate. Его особенность - абстрагирование от запросов. Вы просто создаете запросы спец методами из объекта Session. Благодаря чему можно спокойно менять бд просто переписав 1/2 строки в конфиге. А маппинг вродь и сам jdbc реализует.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim В некоторых нюансах и не сложных sql запросов Hibernate упрощает код, и габариты текста в разы, но вот когда нужно выполнить сложный запрос происходит беда.

Comment: Я их сохранял как вьюшки. Или на месте обрабатывал. Для подсчета там есть метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хочу поделиться своим решением данной проблемы, для того что бы работал наш запрос нужно определиться как мы будем обращаться к базе это важно в Hibernate, я при запросе такого вида:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
String sqll = "select nkl, tzav, psum,lsum,ltl, lth, diam, ddiam,nv,nvp from zxp.valpr where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl,MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=0 group by nkl ) and pvn=0 and rop=0 order by 1";
 SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
//query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
query.addEntity(workval.class);
List res = query.list();       
request.getRequestDispatcher("4kl/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Допустил следующую ошибку а именно - чтобы получить список скаляров (значения ) из одной или нескольких таблиц приведем следующий синтаксис:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
String sqll = "select nkl, tzav, psum,lsum,ltl, lth, diam, ddiam,nv,nvp from zxp.valpr where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl,MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=0 group by nkl ) and pvn=0 and rop=0 order by 1";
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    //query.addEntity(workval.class);
    List res = query.list();       
request.getRequestDispatcher("4kl/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Для наглядности я оставил закомментированые строки. И вот теперь можно проверять, да действительно наш запрос отработал
Test:  [{LTH=8.5021533203125, DDIAM=492, NKL=1, PSUM=247.512298583984, TZAV=2016-03-21 10:59:55.0, LTL=0, DIAM=492, NV=86, NVP=92, LSUM=8.5021533203125}
Если же вам нужно выполнить запрос с использованием query.addEntity(workval.class);
Тогда нужно выполнить запрос следующим образом:

```
String sqll = "select * from zxp.valpr where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl,MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=0 group by nkl ) and pvn=0 and rop=0 order by 1";
```

Всем спасибо кто помогал мне разобраться с проблемой.